# What is right way to deal with "N+1" + Count problem?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

Supose the model as below:

```
class public Post
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get;set;}
}
```

in the Posts/Index Page, I want to show a list of Post, with the Count of comments of each post (not total number of comments of all posts).

1: If I use

```
context.Posts.Include("Comments")
```

it will load the whole entity of all related commments , in fact I only need the Count of Comments.

2: If I get the count of each post one by one:

```
var commentCount = context.Entry(post)
                      .Collection(p => p.Comments)
                      .Query()
                      .Count();
```

that is a N+1 problem.

Any one knows the right way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need this for your presentation layer / view model? In such case create specialized ViewModel

```
public class PostListView 
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int CommentsCount { get; set; }
}
```

And use query with projection:

```
var data = context.Posts
                  .Select(p => new PostListView
                      {
                          Post = p,
                          CommentsCount = p.Comments.Count()
                      });
```

And you are done. If you need it you can flatten your `PostListView` so that it contains `Post`'s properties instead of `Post` entity.

Comment: If I understand right, using this solution, it still need N+1 select SQL statements, right?

for each post, EF will load all related comments in memory, then caculate count in Linq to entity.

is there some way can generate one SQL statement to get the count and not load comment entities?

thank you!

Comment: No this is single statement because count is executed in database as part of complex SQL.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
public class PostView
{
    public String PostName { get; set; }
    public Int32 PostCount { get; set; }
}

public static IEnumerable<PostView> GetPosts()
    {
        var context = new PostsEntities();

        IQueryable<PostView> query = from posts in context.Posts
                                     select new PostView
                                                {
                                                    PostName = posts.Title,
                                                    PostCount = posts.PostComments.Count()
                                                };

        return query;
    }
```

Then use something like this:

```
foreach (PostView post in GetPosts())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Post Name: {0}, Post Count: {1}", post.PostName, post.PostCount));
        }
```

Should display the list as so:

- Post name (12)
- Post name (1)

Etc etc

Comment: Thank you! your anwser is same as Ladislav Mrnka'.

Comment: Not a problem, i had the window open a little long while i tested the solution.

Is this on the lines of what you wanted though?